# Combinatorics and nested for loops

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Suppose I have the below array:

```
val x  = Array(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,5,6),Array(7,8,9))
```

and want to get all the combinations like so:

(1,4,7)
(1,4,8)
(1,4,9)
(1,5,7)
(1,5,8)
(1,5,9)
(1,6,7)...
(3,6,7)
(3,6,8)
(3,6,9)

I would write :

```
  def comb = for (
      a <- 0 until 3;
      b <- 0 until 3;
      c <- 0 until 3
    ) yield (x(0)(a),x(1)(b),x(2)(c))
    comb foreach println
```

I want to know a more efficient way to do it , using less memory as I need to do it for a 10x16 array and not for a 3x3.

I have tried making 16 nested loops but I run out of memory as (I believe) it has to make 10^16 combinations.

Comment: If you just need to print the values, you can   `for (
      a <- 0 until 3;
      b <- 0 until 3;
      c <- 0 until 3
    ) println (x(0)(a),x(1)(b),x(2)(c))`  That way, you are storing up any values and using memory.

Comment: I do need the values to be saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 10x16 array you will have 10^16 combinations in the memory as the output. The only thing you can do here - receive it lazy, using iterators instead of lists:

```
def comb = for (
  a <- 0 until 3 toIterator;
  b <- 0 until 3 toIterator;
  c <- 0 until 3 toIterator
) yield (x(0)(a),x(1)(b),x(2)(c))
```

After that you can map + reduce results before output.

You may also look at Streams, but they are saving results to the memory during iteration - so you will have to reduce them before applying any side effects (like foreach).

Comment: That's a nice thought! Thank you for the reply.